# WCF CustomToken error " security token with the 'Basic' attachment mode must be signed."

Tags: c#, wcf

So I have created a custom token, based mostly from the MSDN example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872.aspx) but I can't seem to get it to work. I always get this error " security token with the 'Basic' attachment mode must be signed." in the logs. I have been over the code base several times and 
 A) obviously it compiles and runs 
 B) I can't see where the issue is. 
The log message isn't all that helpful. I thought it might be something with the cert but I have beat that to death and created a couple different certs (one using server name set to localhost etc...).

A Google search for this turns up almost nothing.

Anyone got a clue what this is, or just tell me where I can maybe look? Like I said - I have been through this code many times, I see the authorization policy get created and all that good stuff, I can see the certificate is set, I just don't know where else to look, I really don't have any code to post, there are so many classes you have to implement. If someone has an idea of what maybe I can look at I will be happy to post that particular class / code snippet.

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled tracing and followed the request path to see where the exception originated and the parameters at that point.  Service Trace Viewer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

Comment: Yeah - That is how I got that error message, the message from the client is even more vague. With verbose logging on, just before the error I can my service receives a message, I can see that it has a UID for the encryption key then the next message is an error and really that is about it - no header tree to look at or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wcf/thread/F822CCB9-A8A1-474F-87AF-E5CD9EC34494

> ... wasn't copying the "id" property of the security token correctly.
>   This was causing a new ID to get created for the security token on the server, which no longer matched the security signature data, and so the message would be rejected.

In your implementation of your custom `WSSecurityTokenSerializer` to serialize your security token, you probably aren't copying the `Id` property of the token.  The ID needs to match from the client to the server.

A common mistake (one that I'm sure I've made too) is to just `id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` in the constructor. That is fine for its initial creation on the clinet, but when it deserializes on the server, it needs to use the same ID from the client, not a new guid again.